# How to write multi line comments in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

How to comment multiple lines of code in classic asp at once?I have tried using ' for every line that I want to comment.But, that is not the best way to do I believe.Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server-side comments: What's the equivalent of <%-- --%> in ASP Classic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431170/server-side-comments-whats-the-equivalent-of-in-asp-classic)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34536511/20126

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<!-- METADATA  
  comment
-->
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that normally comments are tied to the scripting language used so if JScript was used multi-line comments are built in `/* */`. By default though Classic ASP uses VBScript which doesn't support multi-line comments. This trick will work for any of the scripting languages because it is handled by the Classic ASP pre-processor but it's worth noting that this will only work for Classic ASP. If you were working with VBScript standalone this will not work.

Comment: I agree - this is a hack.

Comment: @Paul I'm not condemning the practice just pointing out the flaws. It is indeed a hack though, but a clever one.

Comment: 1. How is this a hack? 2. If you try to put something like this into your actual vbscript code, i.e. *within* the `<% %>` tags, it'll blow up in your face. Perhaps the answer should make that clear?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "multi-line comments" in ASP - my suggestion for a quick dirty fix:

```
if False then
 ...
 code to be 'commented'
 ...
end if
```